# move_uploaded_file() failed to open stream and move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move

Tags: php, apache, chmod

I am doing a file upload page , that will rename the file before adding it , and i am getting those errors.
I've tried `chmod -R 777 ./` in the folder of the website but it still doesn't work.

```
 $dir = Users::currentUser()->id;//each user have his folder
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir . DS))
    {
      echo "The file has been uploaded as ".$ran2.$ext;
        //Router::redirect('upload');
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }
```

The `PROOT` is defined by me as the website root folder `define('PROOT','/framework/');` and the `DS` is the separator `(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') ? define('DS', '/') : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`.

And this is how the error looks

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/framework/files/4/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/framework/app/controllers/UploadController.php on line 46


Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpHz70FG' to '/framework/files/4/' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/framework/app/controllers/UploadController.php on line 46
```

And i am also getting the error from the `if` statement

`Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.`

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI3aS.jpg) is a picture of my files structure

> Update

The problem were cause of ubuntu permissions , on windows it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
define('PROOT','framework/');
(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') ? define('DS', '/') : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)

$dir = Users::currentUser()->id;//each user have his folder
$path = PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir . DS;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$path)
    {
      echo "The file has been uploaded as ".$ran2.$ext;
        //Router::redirect('upload');
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }
```

Comment: $path = PROOT . 'files' . DS . $dir . DS; give the echo the path variable what you will get

Answer (score 0):

you have to use absolute path
like

```
 define('PROOT','/opt/lampp/htdocs/framework/');
```